# Ubuntu One stop syncing after Software Center logging in with another identity

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, software-center, login

I use U1 on Ubuntu 11.04 with no problems until today.

For the first time, I used Software Center's rating function and give 5 stars to my  favourite paint application. I need to login before doing that, and I choose the email address used for my launchpad account (el.cameleon.1@...), which is dedicated to my activity on internet (forum, bugzilla, mailing list,...).

However, for my UbuntuOne account, I use another email address (my private one). I am not sure if it related, but I guess that  login with my launchpad account disconnect me from U1, because now I have a message that tell me that I am not connected and to check my connection to the internet (which is fine, thanks).

Any idea? How can I log off in order to identify again into U1? Is it possibile to use one launchpad account for SoftwareCenter rating and another One for UbuntuOne?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary work around you can simply delete the entries in seahorse for ubuntu one and ubuntu software center.  You should then be able to log back into both with the correct user and everything work again.